# Does MotoPlus and Motonis require Windows OS? Where to download motoplus/motonis?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need to controll a robot with the DX100 controller, I need some sort of sdk which can give me the possibility to program the controller. (Need to send stop signals at first..)

Do the MotoPlus require me to have windows OS?
Is there somewhere you can download MotoPlus or Motonis and try it out?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/83021/does-motoplus-and-motonis-require-windows-os?-where-to-download-motoplus/motonis?/) by [Mr Hillgren](https://answers.ros.org/users/7066/mr-hillgren/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2013-09-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-09-24**:
This doesn't seem ROS related. Is it?

**Comment by [Mr Hillgren](https://answers.ros.org/users/7066/mr-hillgren/) on 2013-09-24**:
I've been having trouble getting started with ROS and I need to integrate some sort of controller with ROS to communicate with the robot. It was the tutorial I found in ROS which lead me to the Motoplus SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should contact Motoman to get info on MotoPlus  Tell them you intend to use it with ROS. They should be able to tell you if it is required or not. As far as I understand the IDE is not needed for straight motion control. The binaries for this are checked in to the public repo.

If you are developing something special, I recommend looking at the motoman_driver package ( http://wiki.ros.org/motoman_driver ) to see how it can be done.

---

Originally posted by [sedwards](https://answers.ros.org/users/78/sedwards/) with karma: 1601 on 2013-09-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mr Hillgren](https://answers.ros.org/users/7066/mr-hillgren/) on 2013-09-25**:
Thank you! =)